# detect file difference (change) with `ansible`

Tags: ansible

In this task I found a roundabout method to compare two files (`dconfDump` and `dconfDumpLocalCurrent`) and to set a variable (previously defined as `false`) to true if the two files differ.

The solution seem to work, but it looks ugly and, as a beginner with `ansible`, I have the impression a better solution should be existing.

```
---
# vars file for dconfLoad
local_changed : false
target_changed : false

---

- name: local changed is true when previous target different then local current  
  shell:  diff /home/frank/dconfDump /home/frank/dconfDumpLocalCurrent
  register: diff_oldtarget_localCurrent
  register: local_changed  
  ignore_errors: true
- debug:
    msg: CHANGED LOCALLY 
  when: local_changed
```

Some background to the task, which is an attempt to synchronize files: A file `LocalCurrent` is compared with `LocalOld` and `CurrentTarget`, to determine if the `LocalCurrent` is changed and if it is different than `currentTarget`. If `LocalCurrent` is not changed and `CurrentTarget` is changed, then apply the change (and set `LocalOld` to `CurrentTarget`); if `LocalCurrent` is changed then upload to controller.

What is the appropriate approach with `ansible`? Thank you for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use stat to get the checksum and then compare it. Please see below.

```
   tasks:
   - name: Stat of dconfDump
     stat:
      path : "/tmp/dconfDump"
     register: dump

   - name: SHA1 of dconfDump
     set_fact:
      dump_sha1: "{{ dump.stat.checksum }}"

   - name: Stat of dconfDumpLocalCurrent
     stat:
      path : "/tmp/dconfDumpLocalCurrent"
     register: dump_local

   - name: SHA1 of dconfDumpLocalCurrent
     set_fact:
      local_sha1: "{{ dump_local.stat.checksum }}"

   - name: Same
     set_fact:
      val: "False"
     when:  dump_sha1 != local_sha1

   - name: Different
     set_fact:
      val: "True"
     when:  dump_sha1 == local_sha1

   - name: Print
     debug:
      msg: "{{val}}"
```

Comment: interesting new functions! why do you use `set_fact`? and before register - what is the difference?  -- what would be a method to have a 'subroutine' like construction for each file (stat and SHA1)?

Comment: You can also remove both the SHA1 tasks and just add a condition as when:  dump.stat.checksum != dump_local.stat.checksum for the task-Same and when:  dump.stat.checksum == dump_local.stat.checksum for the task-Different. set_fact was given to understand it better.

Comment: this is helpful; I may do this! - just to learn it, could you point me to a document to learn how one could to 'subroutines' with arguments?

Comment: sorry, subroutines I am not sure

Comment: you can mark as answer or upvote the answer if you found it helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Use [stat](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/collections/ansible/builtin/stat_module.html#ansible-builtin-stat-retrieve-file-or-file-system-status) and create dictionary of checksums. For example

```yaml
    - stat:
        path: "{{ item }}"
      loop:
        - LocalOld
        - LocalCurrent
        - CurrentTarget
      register: result
    - set_fact:
        my_files: "{{ dict(paths|zip(chkms)) }}"
      vars:
        paths: "{{ result.results|map(attribute='stat.path')|list }}"
        chkms: "{{ result.results|map(attribute='stat.checksum')|list }}"
    - debug:
        var: my_files
```

gives (abridged) if all files are the same

```yaml
  my_files:
    CurrentTarget: 7c73e9f589ca1f0a1372aa4cd6944feec459c4a8
    LocalCurrent: 7c73e9f589ca1f0a1372aa4cd6944feec459c4a8
    LocalOld: 7c73e9f589ca1f0a1372aa4cd6944feec459c4a8
```

Then use the dictionary to compare the checksums and copy files. For example

```yaml
    # If LocalCurrent is not changed and CurrentTarget is changed,
    # then apply the change (and set LocalOld to CurrentTarget)

    - debug:
        msg: Set LocalOld to CurrentTarget
      when:
        - my_files['LocalCurrent'] == my_files['LocalOld'] 
        - my_files['LocalCurrent'] != my_files['CurrentTarget'] 

    - debug:
        msg: Do not copy anything
      when:
        - my_files['LocalCurrent'] == my_files['LocalOld'] 
        - my_files['LocalCurrent'] == my_files['CurrentTarget']
```

gives

```yaml
TASK [debug] ****
skipping: [localhost]

TASK [debug] ****
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: Do not copy anything
```

Comment: thank you - this is much cleaner! your solution has showed me a few new tricks I had not seen how to use!

Comment: what is the advantage of creating an array with the value compared to just use three variable names?